# Why does my simple rounding trick not work?

Tags: c, rounding

I expect that if I add 0.5 to a double and then truncate the value to round a double to the nearest integer. However, in the following code it doesn't work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a,b,d;
  double c;
  a = 54325;
  b = 7858;

  c = a/b;
  c = c+0.5;           /* rounding trick */

  d = (int)c;          /* truncate integer */
  printf("%d\n",d);
  return 0;
}
```

54325/7858 should result in 6.91, so if I add 0.5 and then truncate the value, my answer should be 7. However, I get 6 as result. Why?

Comment: Your rounding trick is not a very good way to round numbers, especially when C has its own tested implementations.

Comment: So what would you recommend?

Comment: [`round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 c=a/b;
```

is an integer division as both operands of `/` are of integer types. This is the case even if here `c` is of type `double`.

To have a floating point division you need one operand of the `/` operator to be  of floating point type:

```
 c = (double) a / b;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because this expression

```
c=a/b;
```

produces an integer result: it does not matter that you assign it to a `double` - the division of two `int`s is always an `int`.

Fix it by adding a cast:

```
c=(double)a/b;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a rookie, so I still brushing up my basics.

Answer (score 1):

*"54325/7858 should result in 6.91"*

No, it does not.

Integer **54,325** divided by integer **7,858**, results in integer **6**.

There is no `.91`, because `int / int = int`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `54325/7858` is an *integer division*. There is no rounding involved
at all. It just tells you how many times can divisor (`7858`) *fit* into divider
(`54325`). Integer division is also coupled to integer remainder so when:

```
div = a / b;
rem = a % b;
```

then this holds:

```
div * b + rem == a
```

it could never hold if any kind of rounding would have been involved.

If you want rounding, cast at least one value to `double` (or `float`) and then use one of these:

```
#include <math.h>
...
double c = (double)a / b;
double rounded_to_nearest = round(c);
double rounded_up         = ceil(c);
double rounded_down       = floor(c);
```